# What is the difference between these groups?

Tags: group-theory, solid-geometry, platonic-solids

Could someone please explain the difference between the group of all icosahedral symmetries and S5? I know that the former is a direct product, but don't they work the same? Say I have an icosahedron, why wouldn't S5 work as a description of its symmetries? Thank you very much.

**Added:** When counting the symmetries of a platonic solid, in this case the icosahedron, Does it include reflecting along a plane cutting through the solid, in a sort of turing itself inside out reflection? I read that the symmetries counted should be "orientation-preserving". What does that mean?

Comment: If you don't even know how to define the group of icosahedral symmetries, how are you going to answer this question?  Presumably, if this is a question from somewhere, then it probably included reflections, since there are only 60 icosahedral symmetries without reflections, and 120 with reflections, and $|S_5|=120$, so the question would be trivial without reflections

Comment: (Orientation-preserving is the same as not counting reflections, yes.  There are a number of different definitions for preserving orientation,  but one meaning is by representing your symmetry as a matrix.  Then it is "orientation-preserving" if the determinant of the matrix is positive.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : You are quite right. I was thinking that the question is a little strange since there are only 60 rotational symmetries. As to why S5 is not a right representation of the group of icosahedral symmetries, I was told that there is a simple reason as to why it can't be true without knowing that the group is isomorphic to $A_5\times \{\pm 1\}$, but I still don't see it

Comment: Anton, are you preparing to exam on the geometry course by Sossinsky in Independent University of Moscow?

Comment: Hi, Sergey, actually I am not :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: If $g$ is the symmetry that send each point to it's opposite point in the icosahedron, then show $\{1,g\}$ is a normal subgroup of the group of symmetries.  Show that $S_5$ does not have any normal subgroup of order $2$.

Comment: This is very easy to do with matrices (the matrix is -1).  Is it easy to see from a more elementary idea of symmetry?  I guess one only needs to see it commutes with rotations.  I teach a freshmen non-stem course, and they would not understand the matrix argument.

Comment: If $h$ is a symmetry, then $h$ sends opposite points to opposite points.  This means that $g(h(x))=h(g(x))$ - the point oppsite $h(x)$ is the image under $h$ of the point opposite to $x$.  But this means that $gh=hg$, for any $h$. @JackSchmidt

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. Can I prove the second bit by saying that a normal subgroup must be a union of conjugacy classes and there is no combination of ccl in S5 that has only 2 elements?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: perfect, thanks. "being opposite is a geometric property"

Comment: (This fact that any $h$ must commute with $g$ is "intuitive," but we can also see it by the fact that $h$ is an isometry, and, for any vertex $x$ of the icosahedron, the there is exactly one point $y$ on the icosahedron with $d(x,y)=D$, where $D$ is the diameter of the icosahedron, and that $y$ is $g(x)$.  So if $x$ is a vertex and $h$ any symmetry, then $d(h(x),h(g(x)))=d(x,g(x))=D$.  So $h(g(x))$ is of distance $D$ from $h(x)$, which is uniquely $g(h(x))$, so $h(g(x))=g(h(x))$ for all vertices $x$, and hence $hg=hg$

Comment: @Anton: yup, except you probably want two conjugacy classes each of size 1.  S5 only has one of those, the identity.  Who is the other mysterious element?

Comment: @Anton More elementary, I'd just note that the only elements of order $2$ in $S_5$ must be either transpositions of a pair $(a b)$ or a product of disjoint transpositions, $(a b)(c d)$.  Then show that the groups generated by such elements can't be normal. (Hint: There is always at least one element fixed by an element of order 2 in $S_5$.)

Comment: In particular, if $\sigma$ is an element of order two in $S_n$ for $n\geq 3$, then then since $\sigma\neq 1$, there is an $a\in\{1,...,n\}$ such that $\sigma(a)\neq a$ and a $b\in\{1,2,...n\}$ so that $a\neq b$ and $\sigma(a)\neq b$.  Let $\alpha\in S_n$ be the transposition $(a b)$.  Then $$\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1}(b) = \alpha\sigma(a) = \sigma(a) \neq a = \sigma(b)$$  So $\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1}\neq \sigma$ so $\{1,\sigma\}$ cannot be a normal subgroup of $S_n$.

Comment: Whoops, typo in that last argument. That last line should be:$$\alpha\sigma\alpha^{-1}(b) = \alpha\sigma(a) = \sigma(a) \neq \sigma(b)$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JackSchmidt: the mysterious element? could you be thinking of -1?

Comment: @Anton: in the (full) icosahedral group yes, but in S5 there is no such element, just like Thomas Andrews said.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Thanks! I have a very stuid question: What exactly is a symmetry? In my understanding it is something we can do to a figure/object so that it is mapped to its original form without breaking the edges joining the vertices. Would this be right? If so, what is the -1 symmetry doing? if it is the g Thomas mentioned ie it sends all the points to their oposite points does the figure get all tangled up? and what plane is the reflection done wrt?

Comment: @Anton: Your understanding is good (that is called a combinatorial, or graph symmetry).  Thomas Andrews in his second reply to me used the understanding "a mapping that never changes distance" (a metric isometry).  The -1 symmetry is a very special feature of 3D; a "super-reflection" formed from 3 reflections in the XY-, XZ-, and YZ- planes.  You can think of it as turning something inside out.  It is also called an "inversion".  It is not the reflection over any plane, but it is the only non-rotation that is not a reflection+rotation.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Two groups are treated as same if there is an isomorphism between them.A simple reason why $S_5$ cannot be used to describe the symmetries of an icosahedron(whose group of symmetries we will call $I_h$) is that its structure is fundamentally different from that of $I_h$.  For starters, $S_5$ cannot be expressed as a direct product of two groups unlike $I_h$, for which it is possible to do so. So $S_5$ cannot be isomorphic to $I_h$.

Comment: Thanks, Fortuon, is there an argument that does not involve knowing the group $I_h$ beforehand?

Comment: Perhaps we can show that the group of all its symmetries must be a direct product?